# Binding RibbonGroup.GroupSizeDefinitions does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, ribboncontrolslibrary

We are using Microsoft ribbon control library for .Net 4.0.

I was trying to bind RibbonGroup.GroupSizeDefinitions to a property of the ViewModel. If we declare the binding in Xaml as follows it is working fine.

```
<ribbon:RibbonGroup Header="Group1" GroupSizeDefinitions="{Binding GroupDefinitions}" />
```

However if I set this using a Style this is not working.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:RibbonGroup}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ribbon:RibbonGroup}}">
    <Setter Property="GroupSizeDefinitions" Value="{Binding GroupDefinitions}" />
</Style>
```

How can I bind this to the View Model ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I was able to make it work.

I added an attached property and binded to the collection in the view model. Then on attached property change call back, a new RibbonGroupSizeDefinitionBaseCollection is created and added items of the collection. Then assigned the new RibbonGroupSizeDefinitionBaseCollection to RibbonGroup.GroupSizeDefinitions property.